# Constantly check if a process is open

Tags: c#

I want to constantly check if a background process is running or not, I only have one label (to display the result)
My code that shows whether it's running or not is:

```
Process[] plist = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        if (plist.Length > 0)
        {
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            label1.Text = "FOUND";
        }
        else 
        {
            label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label1.Text = "NOT FOUND";
        }
```

And when run it, it works, but when I close the process it still shows "FOUND", how can I make it always check if plist.Lenght is 0 or >0?
p.s: I tried some duplicate questions etc and I didn't get it to work.

Comment: It looks like your code is actually always checking if plist.Length is greater than 0 so I do not believe that is your problem.  Seems like your process is either not actually being closed or it is closed but is still showing up which causes plist to always be greater than 0

Comment: @dogyear Thanks for the answer, but I am pretty sure it closes, and I believe it just checks if it's 0 or >0 on runtime, not constantly.

Comment: If that's the case then Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome") is probably not returning the list of processes you think because if you step through your code in the debugger I believe you will see that it's checking the length of plist every time it is run and plist is greater than 0.  I would definitely step through the debugger and see what the code is actually doing if you haven't already done so

Comment: We'll need a bit more code to see what you are doing in context. Is this in a loop, a timer etc.. why do you expect it to run more than once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Program
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Process[] plist = Process.GetProcessesByName("msedge");
      if (plist.Length > 0)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(plist[0].ProcessName);
      }
      else
      {
        Console.WriteLine("NotFound");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code above seems to be working just fine.  Two things I would check are:

- open up task manager [image: task manager]
  ensure all chrome processes are closed, even if your chrome web browser is closed, there might be some open here.  I used msedge, and it seemed to work just fine.
- You may have hard looped your UI thread. This means it is so busy checking processes, that it has no time to update your label.  normally you do not do tasks like this on the UI thread, but instead break them off on side threads.  Alternatively you can use a timer on the main thread, check every couple of miliseconds. The last but *Bad* way to do this is to call:

```
label1.Invalidate();
Application.DoEvents();
```

These lines will force the UI to update and pause your process check, but is really only good for testing / development.  As this will cause all of your processes to lag, not a good thing for production enviroments.